# Don't know what to loop through here

Tags: python-3.x

I found this code online. It's used to extract a sheet from every excel wb in a directory. I'm still learning Python so I don't know what I should be asking exactly.

The error says "sheets" is not defined. Fair enough, but this is the code I found and it says it works. I don't really know what to define here.

```
import os
import win32com.client
 
path = "C:/Folder"  #This folder contains the spreadsheets
pathmaster = "C:/Desktop/MyFile.xlsx"
 
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = False
 
wbmaster = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=pathmaster)
 
os.listdir(path)
 
for sheet in sheets:
    print(sheet)
    wb1 = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=os.path.join(path, sheet))
 
    ws1 = wb1.Worksheets(4)
    ws1.Name = sheet[:4]
 
    ws1.Copy(Before=wbmaster.Worksheets(1))
    wb1.Close(True)
 
wbmaster.Close(SaveChanges=True)
```

Comment: You are looping over sheets (for sheet in sheets) but above that you never define what sheets is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said 'sheets' is undefined. To fix this you need to declare it above your call to it `for sheet in sheets:` Here is how you can fix it.

Change your code to...

```
wbmaster = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=pathmaster)
for sheet in wbmaster.Sheets:
    # Do code here
```

*Check out these other past answers*

1. [How can I iterate over worksheets in win32com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407824/how-can-i-iterate-over-worksheets-in-win32com)
2. [Python: Open Excel Workbook using Win32 COM Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877278/python-open-excel-workbook-using-win32-com-api)

Comment: I'm going to read through those, thank you so much for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

You must define what is sheets before use in the for loop
maybe you must use :
**for sheet in wbmaster**